# Random Back Ground colors for label text

Tags: vb.net

Their is a label named `lbltitle` in my first form to display the title, i had changed its color according to the user logged in. following is the code for choose the color:-

```
Dim n As Integer = Len(userId) Mod 3
Dim lblcolor As Color
Select Case n
Case 0 : lblcolor = Color.Blue
Case 1 : lblcolor = Color.BlueViolet
Case 2 : lblcolor = Color.Red
End Select
lbltitle.ForeColor = lblcolor
```

i shuffle the color on the basics of the length of userId.

i had extended the code by using random number instead for 3 in modules operation then my code will be changed as:

```
 Dim random_no As Random = New Random(2)
 Dim n As Integer = Len(userId) Mod random_no.Next
 Dim lblcolor As Color
 Select Case n
 Case 0 : lblcolor = Color.Blue
 Case 1 : lblcolor = Color.BlueViolet
 Case 2 : lblcolor = Color.Red
 Case 3 : lblcolor = Color.AliceBlue
 Case 4 : lblcolor = Color.DarkGoldenrod
 End Select
 lbltitle.ForeColor = lblcolor
```

My Question is that is their any possibility to generate random colors instead for this?

Comment: Should the user be able to easily view the text of the Label?  Depending on the background color of the Label certain colors may make the Label hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your select case and random numbers with the following code

```
Dim rand As New Random
lbltitle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternatives that set the ForeColor based on the BackColor.  The example cycles through the known colors

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'all KnownColors
    Dim allColors As List(Of Color) = (From ac In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor))
                                       Select Color.FromKnownColor(DirectCast(ac, KnownColor))).ToList


    For Each c As Color In allColors
        Label1.BackColor = c 'try every color as BackColor

        ''alternative 1
        ' ''ForeColor is inverted BackColor
        ''Dim R As Integer = Not c.R
        ''Dim G As Integer = Not c.G
        ''Dim B As Integer = Not c.B
        ''Label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Label1.BackColor.A, R, G, B)

        'alternative 2
        Dim R As Integer = c.R
        Dim G As Integer = c.G
        Dim B As Integer = c.B
        If (R * R + G * G + B * B) < 128 * 128 Then
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.White
        Else
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
        Label1.Refresh()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use button when clicked color chaenged in random

`Public Class Form1`

```
Dim rnd As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.lbltitle.foreColor = Color.FromArgb(255, rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255))
End Sub
```

`End Class`